# Weird bug when testing contract in foundry

Tags: solidity, testing, foundry

I am creating a ERC20 token solidity contract and when writing tests I encountered a problem.

Here is a function I use to test the token cap with.

```
function testTokenCap() public {
    uint256 mintValueCap = mintValue + token.cap();

    vm.expectRevert();
    vm.prank(OWNER);
    token.mint(USER, mintValueCap);
}
```

This function works fine but the weird thing is that if write the function like this:

```
function testTokenCap() public {
    vm.expectRevert();
    vm.prank(OWNER);
    token.mint(USER, mintValue + token.cap());
}
```

Then `vm.prank(OWNER)` sends the test contract's address and not the owner's one which causes my function to revert because I have an `onlyOwner` modifier:

```
modifier onlyOwner {
    require(msg.sender == i_owner, "Only owner can use this function");
    _;
}
```

I am guessing that `vm.prank(OWNER)` executes `mintValue + token.cap()` as the `msg.sender` to do the calculation and the test contract is left to execute `token.mint()` contract so it passes it's address. I am just starting with solidity and blockchain technology and I would like to know if I am thinking correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your question correctly. `vm.prank(address)` will set `mgs.sender` only [for the next call](https://book.getfoundry.sh/cheatcodes/prank), which is `token.cap()`. If you want to fix your test you can do one of two things:

1. use `vm.startPrank(address)` in combination with `vm.stopPrank()`
2. call `token.cap()` first, store it in a variable and then call `token.mint(address, uint256)` with the `vm.prank(address)`